# When should you await a Task?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous

Say I have a `Repository` class which has a `DbContext`. In this class I have a method:

```
public async Task<T> CreateAsync(T obj)
{
    var o = _dbSet.Add(obj);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    return o;
}
```

In a `Service` class I use this method to create an object:

```
public async Task<MyObject> Create()
{
    return await _repository.CreateAsync(new MyObject());
}
```

And finally in my api controller `MyObjectController` I return this object like so:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
{
    return Ok(await _service.Create());
}
```

I'm confused about all these `async` and `await` keywords. I know that a `Task` is awaitable. Does this mean that I could just return the `Task` from `CreateAsync` without awaiting in neither `CreateAsync` or `Create` and then finally await it in `Get`? Does it have a negative effect on my application that I do my awaits like in the example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this mean that I could just return the Task from CreateAsync without awaiting in neither CreateAsync or Create and then finally await it in Get?

yes you can do that, it is actually more efficient. if you do your awaits as you are doing them, each asynchronous method will generate a state machine which means more code and more context switching

> Does it have a negative effect on my application that I do my awaits like in the example?

There will be a slight performance penalty due to the state machine and the context switching. The cost is typically much less than the cost of the call, but it all adds up in the end. [Async Performance: Understanding the Costs of Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx) is a great article about this topic.

As pointed out by @Richard Szalay, just make sure that you eventually `await` the task otherwise any exceptions that occur will remain unobserved and will be swallowed.

Comment: It's worth noting that the downside to returning a Task without awaiting it is that the method in question won't be in the async callstack if an exception is thrown

Comment: Good point, but he did say that he eventually awaits it in the `Get` method so the exception will get thrown, but I will  point that out explicitly.

Comment: the exception won't be swallowed, but the method that didn't await won't appear on the async callstack (which could make things more difficult to debug)

Answer (score 0):

async and await is used when you want a method to run asynchronously.
async without await is a synchronous

async methods return task or void
await wait for task to complete

so await is used before a method that return task

your Get method is waiting to complete your create() task which waits to complete createAsync Task

and so on.

_dbContext.SaveChangesAsync() is async method so aaawait is required, or else it may return wrong o

Let me know if you need any more clarification

Comment: I am pretty sure OP knows what await/asyn does. His question was more like "Should I use multiple awaits vs a single await"